# Scala type parameter bound error in subclass but not superclass

Tags: scala

Why don't the following work?

```
scala> class Foo[B<:Foo[B]]
defined class Foo

scala> class Goo[B<:Foo[B]](x: B)
defined class Goo

scala> class Hoo[B<:Hoo[B]] extends Foo[Hoo[B]] { def f = new Goo(this) }
defined class Hoo

scala> class Ioo extends Hoo[Ioo] { def g = new Goo(this) }
<console>:11: error: inferred type arguments [Ioo] do not conform to class Goo's type parameter bounds [B <: Foo[B]]
       class Ioo extends Hoo[Ioo] { def g = new Goo(this) }
                                            ^

scala> class Ioo extends Hoo[Ioo] { f } // yet this works!
defined class Ioo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in new `Goo(this)` must be `B <: Foo[B]`. It is Ioo, so we need `Ioo <: Foo[Ioo]`.

`Ioo` is `Hoo[Ioo]`, hence `Foo[Hoo[Ioo]]` (inheritance of `Hoo`), which does not give a `Foo[Ioo]`.